# Icon size adjustement?

Tags: html, css, icons

I want to increase my icon size by using CSS property. Which property can increase the size of the icon?

`<p><i class="fa fa-phone course_phn_icon"></i> Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 9 PM</p>`

I tried width and height properties and font-size also with this class name: `course_phn_icon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fa-*g` .Also refer **[here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/#larger)** .For example   :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<p><i class="fa fa-phone course_phn_icon fa-lg"></i> Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 9 PM</p>
<p><i class="fa fa-phone course_phn_icon fa-2x"></i> Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 9 PM</p>
<p><i class="fa fa-phone course_phn_icon fa-3x"></i> Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 9 PM</p>
<p><i class="fa fa-phone course_phn_icon fa-4x"></i> Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 9 PM</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either

1). use in-build class `fa-*x` or

2). you can do that using `font-size` CSS property.

```css
.icon:before {
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<p><i class="fa fa-phone course_phn_icon fa-2x"></i> Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 9 PM</p>
<p><i class="fa fa-phone course_phn_icon icon"></i> Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 9 PM</p>
```

Comment: @Anudeepsyamprasad  what's not working ? Have you included proper `CDN` and have you given proper `class`? I have made a working snippet above using latest `fontawesome` `version 5`

Comment: <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> I'm using this CDN

Comment: @Anudeepsyamprasad Updated the answer. Please have a look at it now. You need to use pseudo class `:before` for `v-4` .If you feel my answer was helpful, please upvote and accept my answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome icon size can be controlled by `font-size` property. Ex: `font-size: 40px;`. That should work fine.